# How to use Selenium Grid with C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-grid

I'm researching Selenium and have a seminar for my group...
I meet many troubles with this
I use C# language and write a demo SeleniumExample.dll Then I start
selenium RC and NUnit and run it with NUnit to see the test report.
I read testdata from XML.

Here's the SeleniumExample.dll: using System;

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Selenium;

namespace SeleniumExample
{

   public class Success_Login
   {

      //User defined

       private string strURL = "http://newtours.demoaut.com/
mercurywelcome.php";
       private string[] strBrowser = new string[3] { "*iehta",
"*firefox", "*safari" };

       // System defined
       private ISelenium selenium;
               private StringBuilder verificationErrors ;

               [SetUp]
               public void SetupTest()
               {
                       selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444,
this.strBrowser[0], this.strURL);
                       selenium.Start();
                       verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
               }

               [TearDown]
               public void TeardownTest()
               {
                       try
                       {
                               selenium.Stop();
                       }
                       catch (Exception)
                       {
                               // Ignore errors if unable to close the browser
                       }
                       Assert.AreEqual("", verificationErrors.ToString());
               }

               [Test]
       public void Success_LoginTest()
               {
           try
           {
               XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
               XmlNode docNode;

               doc.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
               docNode = doc["TestCase"];

               foreach (XmlNode node in docNode)
               {
                   selenium.Open("/");
                   selenium.Type("userName",
node["username"].InnerText);
                   selenium.Type("password",
node["password"].InnerText);
                   selenium.Click("login");
                   selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("30000");
                   Assert.AreEqual("Find a Flight: Mercury Tours:",
selenium.GetTitle());
               }
           }
           catch (AssertionException e)
           {
               verificationErrors.Append(e.Message);
           }
               }
   }
}
```

Now I want to have a demo that using Selenium Grid (SG) but I don't know
how to do. I read document and understand the way SG works. I install
SG and install Ant1.8. The tests will communicate with  Selenium Hub.
Actually, I just understand the theory I don't know how to make the
tests communicate with Selenium Hub and how to make Selenium Hub
control Selenium RC.

I am a new for Selenium. If anyone know this, please help me. I
appreciate it so much.

THANKS,
Hoang

Answer (score 3):

In reality there is no major difference between Selenium RC and Selenium Grid. The only difference is that with Grid you don't have to know where the RC nodes are but if you use Selenium RC you will have to.

```
string hubAddress = "machineNameWithSeleniumGridHub"

[SetUp]
public void SetupTest()
{
    selenium = new DefaultSelenium(hubAddress, 4444,this.strBrowser[0], this.strURL);
    selenium.Start();
    verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
}
```

When your tests run they will speak to the hub which will then push the commands out to the first available RC. I have a Selenium Tutorial on my [site](http://www.theautomatedtester.co.uk/seleniumtraining/selenium_grid_as_infrastructural_tool.htm). It uses C# and should get you going.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I'm reading your site. Also I try to use selenium grid. I will let you know when i got the result...

Once again, Thanks so much ^^